# What is the format of the RDS Data API schema parameter

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-rds

The `batch_execute_statement` function in Boto3 for the RDS Data API has a `schema` argument that can be passed in (see below) however it doesn't seem to have any affect on the output. Does anyone know what this field should contain? AWS docs are very vague and simply say "The name of the database schema". Any help is much appreciated!

```py
client.batch_execute_statement(
    database='string',
    parameterSets=[
        ...
    ],
    resourceArn='string',
    schema='string',
    secretArn='string',
    sql='string',
    transactionId='string'
)
```

Comment: Are you querying mysql? Mysql doesn't have a separate concept of database and schema, but others like postgres do.

Comment: This is postgresql that I'm querying here.